# Aggregating time series data

Tags: python, data-science

I am no data scientist. I do know python and I currently have to manage time series data that is coming in at a regular interval. Much of this data is all zero's or values that are the same for a long time, and to save memory I'd like to filter them out. Is there some standard method for this (which I am obviously unaware of) or should I implement my own algorithm ?

What I want to achieve is the following:

```
interval  value   result
(summed) 
1         0       0
2         0       # removed
3         0       0
4         1       1
5         2       2
6         2       # removed
7         2       # removed
8         2       2
9         0       0
10        0       0
```

Any help appreciated !

Comment: Could you expand on your rule for which data points are removed? Are you planning to keep the first and last instance of a value? Do you want to do this on an incoming data stream or on the resultant dataframe?

Comment: To save memory and remember values you showed, it's enough to have list which elements indicate interval when given value started. For data provided it would be `[[1, 0], [4, 1], [5, 2], [9, 0]]`.

Comment: @JasonChia Good point. I realized that too when I entered the submit button. Still I wonder whether there is some standard procedure for this in the data science world.

Comment: @rpoleski But If I were to put your data in a chart it will -for example- show a line from [1,0] to [4,1]. But it has to be: [1,0][3,0][4,1]. So the first part (from x=1 to 3) of the line should be horizontal.

Answer (score 0):

You could use pandas query on dataframes to achieve this:

```
import pandas as pd

matrix = [[1,0, 0],
[2, 0, 0],
[3, 0, 0],
[4, 1, 1],
[5, 2, 2],
[6, 2, 0],
[7, 2, 0],
[8, 2, 2],
[9, 0, 0],
[10,0, 0]]


df = pd.DataFrame(matrix, columns=list('abc'))
print(df.query("c != 0"))
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll give that a go !

Answer (score 0):

There is no quick function call to do what you need. The following is one way

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'interval':[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
             'value':[0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0]}) # example dataframe


df['group'] = df['value'].ne(df['value'].shift()).cumsum() # column that increments every time the value changes

df['key'] = 1 # create column of ones
df['key'] =  df.groupby('group')['key'].transform('cumsum') # get the cumulative sum 

df['key'] = df.groupby('group')['key'].transform(lambda x: x.isin( [x.min(), x.max()])) # check which key is minimum and which is maximum by group

df = df[df['key']==True].drop(columns=['group', 'key']) # keep only relevant cases

df
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code:

```py
l = [0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0]

for (i, ll) in enumerate(l):
    if i != 0 and ll == l[i-1] and i<len(l)-1 and ll == l[i+1]: 
        continue
    print(i+1, ll)
```

It produces what you want. You haven't specified format of your input data, so I assumed they're in a list. The conditions `ll == l[i-1]` and `ll == l[i+1]` are key to skipping the repeated values.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all!
Looking at the answers I guess I can conclude I'll need to roll my own. I'll be using your input as inspiration.
Thanks again !

Comment: I suggest you indicate which answer is best by giving clicking ^. You got different approaches and they give different results. Others may find it useful.